# how to export queried result from db browser sqlite to google drive

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

i have a table with over six millions rows and i want to query them and save the result as a google sheet document but I don't know how.

as well I would like to know how to save the result as a new table in the database

Answer (score 1):

This code here should be able to make a new table from your query.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
  SELECT expressions
  FROM existing_tables
  [WHERE conditions];
```

Regarding the data transfer I would recommend using a converter website, like sql to xlsx and then opening the xlsx file in Google drive, that's at least how I move data from SQL to Google drive or Excel.